# Reversing list, with no reverse function, in python

Tags: python, list

im trying to reverse a list, here's my code, but for some reason, i keep getting an indexerror.

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
y = len(list1)
c = 1

for x in range(1,int(len(list1)/2)):
    list1[c], list1[y] = list1[y], list1[c]
    y -= 1 
    c += 1
```

so basically i want my output to be [4,3,2,1] why does it keep saying error?

Comment: Indexing starts at 0 and ends at `len(lst) - 1`

Comment: Index starts from 0, `len() - 1` ends, not starts from 1, `len()` ends.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, the first element is at an index of `0`, and the last is at `len(lst) - 1`.

```
def reverse(xs):
    i = 0
    j = len(xs) - 1
    while i < len(xs) // 2:
        xs[i], xs[j] = xs[j], xs[i]
        i += 1
        j -= 1
```

Or more succinctly:

```
def reverse(xs):
    for i in range(len(xs) // 2):
        j = len(xs) - i - 1
        xs[i], xs[j] = xs[j], xs[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use slicing to reverse list here's how

```
listOrg = [1,2,3,4,5]
listReverse = listOrg[::-1]

print(listOrg)
print(listReverse)
```

Comment: The intent is clear from the question that the reversal should be *in situ*. This answer creates a new list

Answer (score 0):

Consider go through the list from end to start:

```
    new_reversed_list = []
    for i in range(len(list1)-1, -1, -1)
         new_reversed_list.append(i)
    print(new_reversed_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = len(a) - 1
c = 0
for i in range(0,int(len(a))//2):    
    a[c] , a[b] = a[b] , a[c]   
    c += 1
    b -= 1
print(a)
```

1. You have took wrong start for indexing ie. c should be equal 0 as indexing starts from 0.
2. The index in your 6th line "list1[y]" cannot be indexed as y is the length of list ie. 4 and the maximum index is only till 3.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea of having two indexes, start and end, is sane. However, there's no need to compute the number of iterations beforehand. Just keep iterating until `start` becomes greater than `end`:

```
start = 0
end = len(ls) - 1

while start < end:
    ls[start], ls[end] = ls[end], ls[start]
    start += 1
    end -= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`y = len(list1)` is 4 but range index start from 0 to 3, so list indice `y` got list index out of range error because can't find index 4.

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
y = len(list1)-1
c = 0

for x in range(y):
    list1[c], list1[y] = list1[y], list1[c]
    c += 1
    y -= 1
```

You can also use list comprehension start from `len()` of the list1 to index 0 with step -1:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
list1 = [x for x in range(len(list1), 0, -1)]
```

or indice slicing:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
list1 = list1[::-1]
```